# Get all post from specific category when get the category name from url in json format?

Tags: php, json, wordpress

```
<?php
   include("../wp-config.php");
   // set header for json mime type
   header('Content-type: application/json;');
   //$output = array('categories' => array());
   $categories=$_GET['name'];
   $post=get_posts('category_name='.$categories.'&posts_per_page=-1');
   $category_query_args = array(
   //'cat_name' => $categories,
             'post' => $post
      );
   //print_r($category_query_args); 
    $category_query = new WP_Query($category_query_args);
    if ( $category_query->have_posts() )
    {
     while ($category_query->have_posts())
      {
         $jsonpost=$category_query->the_post();
         $jsonpost['title']= get_the_title();
         $jsonpost['date'] = get_the_date();
      }
    }
   $output['category_details'][] =  $jsonpost;
   /*======== PRODUCT COLLECTION OUTPUT AS JSON FORMAT ======*/
    echo (json_encode($output));
 ?>
```

I want to get all the posts in a category. The category is get from the url.In the above code, i'm getting a single post in that category.Want to get all posts.Need help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your "$output['category_details'][] =  $jsonpost;" out of the while bucle, ¿it's this?

Comment: When i place it inside the loop i'm getting all the post in all categories.I want to get the all posts in a single category which is from the url

Comment: expecting some other suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is that you are initializing the $jsonpost array en each iteration:

```
$jsonpost=$category_query->the_post();
```

So, at the end of the loop your array has just one entry.

You can use one array to fetch and other array to push

Comment: Then how can i get my desired result @Enrique?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

  include("../wp-config.php");
  // set header for json mime type
  header('Content-type: application/json;');
  //$output = array('categories' => array());
  $categories=$_GET['name'];
  $args = array('numberposts=' => -1, 'category_name' => $categories);
  $myposts = get_posts($args);
    foreach( $myposts as $post )
     {
        $id=$post->ID;
        $image=wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($id, 'thumbnail') );  
            $date=get_the_date();
            $content=apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); 

        $cat_output['posts'][] = array(
                                    'name' => get_the_title($post->ID),
                                    'image' => $image,
                                    'date' => $date,
                                    'Content' => $content
                                    );
     }

    $output['categories'][] = $cat_output;


    header("Content-type: application/json");
    die(json_encode($output));
 ?>
```

By using the above code, i have got my desired result.But i don't find out why i'm getting the result when I'm using the **WP_Query**.If anyone came to know, kindly post your suggestion.
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Try this (just changed NEW/EDIT lines)

```
<?php
include("../wp-config.php");
// set header for json mime type
header('Content-type: application/json;');
//$output = array('categories' => array());
$categories=$_GET['name'];
$post=get_posts('category_name='.$categories.'&posts_per_page=-1');
$category_query_args = array(
    //'cat_name' => $categories,
    'post' => $post
);
//print_r($category_query_args); 
$category_query = new WP_Query($category_query_args);
if ( $category_query->have_posts() )
{
    $jsonall = array(); // NEW
    while ($category_query->have_posts())
    {
        $jsonpost=$category_query->the_post();
        $jsonpost['title']= get_the_title();
        $jsonpost['date'] = get_the_date();

        $jsonall[] = $jsonpost; // NEW
    }
}
$output['category_details'][] =  $jsonall; // EDIT
/*======== PRODUCT COLLECTION OUTPUT AS JSON FORMAT ======*/
echo (json_encode($output));
?>
```

:)

Comment: Sorry ji.This returns all the category posts.I tried over it

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php
    include("../wp-config.php");
    // set header for json mime type
    header('Content-type: application/json;');
    //$output = array('categories' => array());
    $categories=$_GET['name'];
    //echo $categories;
    // $post=array('category_name='.$categories.'&posts_per_page=-1');
    $post = array('category_name' => $categories);
   //print_r($category_query_args); 
   $category_query = new WP_Query($post);

    while ($category_query->have_posts())
    {
     $jsonpost=$category_query->the_post();
     $jsonpost['title']= get_the_title();
     $jsonpost['date'] = get_the_date();
     $output['category_details'][] =  $jsonpost;
   }

   /*======== PRODUCT COLLECTION OUTPUT AS JSON FORMAT ======*/
   echo (json_encode($output));
  ?>
```

I got the result by using **WP_Query** itself :) I have just removed the **get_posts()**, and passed the **categoryname** in an array ( **$post**). That will be passed to the **WP_Query($post)**. As 
@Enrique Muñoz Rodas said, " $output['category_details'][] =  $jsonpost; " is moved to the **loop**.

Thank you @Enrique Muñoz Rodas !!